pine script Shadowing variable warnnings
Getting the Shadowing variable warnings from part of my code. How can I get rid of these warnings?

get_counts(bool condition_param, float top_price, float btm_price) =>
    var float vol = 0.0
    var int count = 0
    
    if condition_param
        vol := 0.0
        count := 0
    else
        if USE_INTRABAR and bar_index > PIVOT_LENGTH
            [h_arr, l_arr, v_arr] = request.security_lower_tf(syminfo.tickerid, INTRABAR_TF, get_data())
            array.copy( h_arr[PIVOT_LENGTH])
            array.copy( l_arr[PIVOT_LENGTH])
            array.copy( v_arr[PIVOT_LENGTH])
            
            if array.size(v_series) > 0
                for i = 0 to array.size(v_series) - 1
                    if array.get(l_series, i) < top_price and array.get(h_series, i) > btm_price
                        vol += array.get(v_series, i)
        else
            bool price_condition = low[PIVOT_LENGTH] < top_price and high[PIVOT_LENGTH] > btm_price
            if price_condition
                vol += volume[PIVOT_LENGTH]
                count += 1
    
    [count, vol]



Warning at 59:25 The variable 'h_arr' is declared in local scope,
which may not be executed at every update. So, obtaining its
historical values may lead to unexpected results
Warning at 60:25 The variable 'l_arr' is declared in local scope,
which may not be executed at every update. So, obtaining its
historical values may lead to unexpected results
Warning at 61:25 The variable 'v_arr' is declared in local scope,
which may not be executed at every update. So, obtaining its
historical values may lead to unexpected results

Tried several methods but have not found the solution yet.

Please share a minimal reproducible example.
